# Tearing down any open Threads after completing all Python Unittests

Tags: python, multithreading, testing

[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python#325528) discusses at great length why it is not a good idea to kill threads. And I agree when we are talking about an actual program. 
I am writing unit tests for several components as well as some integration tests between them. Some require threading. When tests fail, some threads stay open, locked in a `.get()` call of a queue. This causes the whole test suite to get stuck and not complete. I am running either `ptw` (pytest watch) or a custom loop of pytest with `inotifywait` to watch for changes in my files to rerun the suite.

When all tests have completed, I want the suite to kill any remaining threads to complete the loop and not be stuck on a thread somewhere that is just open because of a test failure. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't an elegant way to stop a thread, but you can set their `daemon` to `True`.

code snippet:

```
import threading

all_child_threads = [thread for thread in threading.enumerate() if thread != threading.main_thread()]
for thread in all_child_threads:
    thread.daemon = True
```

Then they will terminate when main thread terminates.

Comment: This could work, however I wouldn't exactly know where to place it. Theoretically, I could put it into every `tearDownClass` of all classes that use threading in my tests but a global hook would be nicer.

Comment: Isn't it another question? What only I can help you about it: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code

Answer (score 2):

Based on Sraw's response, I was able to set the thread to terminate when the main thread terminates, passing daemon=True when starting the thread:

```
threading.Thread(target=method, daemon=True).start()
```

So when I run my unit tests, for example, it would end the execution instead of keep running forever since there's still a thread running.